# font awesome social media icon stack border

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to build a simple enough social media link for the page footer employing the font awesome icons with a circular background, please code pen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojmJYE

```
 <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background1" ></i>
```

For the rollover effect I want a '1px black border' around the background circle so it changes from 'solid' to 'outline' with icon remaining - but I cant seem to reference the CSS border property for the circle background?

Comment: Why do you have separate icons for the circle? Why not rather just use the social media icons and then add some CSS:

`.icon-background2 {color: #fff; background:#000; display:block; border-radius:50%; text-align:center; width:50px; height:50px; line-height:50px;}`

Answer (score 4):

Its very simple. give `border` in `hover` state !!

I have given `border-radius: 50%` and `1px solid #000 border` to the icon to get this output

```css
.social-container {
  backgroun: #66ffdc;
  float: right;
  font-size: 1.2em
}
.icon-background1 {
  color: #000
}
.icon-background2 {
  color: #fff;
}
a:hover .icon-background1 {
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000;
}
a:hover .icon-background2 {
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="social-container">
  <a href="" class="fa-stack fa-lg" style="text-decoration:none; margin-top:0">
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background1"></i>
    <i class="fa  fa-facebook fa-stack-1x  icon-background2"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="fa-stack fa-lg" style="text-decoration:none">
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background1"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-stack-1x  icon-background2"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: The border looks bad, though.

Comment: wait. I will come up with a fix :)

Comment: @PaulRedmond Edited the code. replace border property with box-shadow which I think make the icon more beautiful :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to look best to me.

CSS

```
a:hover .icon-background1  {
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0.80);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: I think Chris earlier is probably right and there are numerous other ways to achieve a circle effect. But in the end I used mostly Ajay's code and it came up a treat, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.social-container
{   width: 100%;
    margin: 40px 0 50px;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;}
.social-container li i
{
    width: 42px;
    height: 42px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #aaa9ad;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 42px;
    color: #aaa9ad;
    font-size: 21px;
}

.icon-background1          {color: #000 }
.icon-background2          {color: #fff;}


a:hover .icon-background1  {color: #fff}
a:hover .icon-background2  {color: #000;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul class="social-container">
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```